# Jquery image animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm newbie of Javascript and Jquery.

I am learning img animation and I have a question.

If I want to move the image from bottom left to the top right in window. Is there any better way than my code?

My code doesn't' work then I expected.

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  function startMoving() {
    var img = $("#imageId");
    var imgWidth = img.width();
    var imgHeight = img.height();
    var screenWidth = $(window).innerWeight();
    var screenHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    var c = Math.sqrt((screenWidth*screenWidth+screenHeight*screenWidth));
    var movement = c/10 // This is for the step of movement
    var zScale = (screenWidth+screenHeight)/2;
    var imgZScale = (imgHeight+imgWidth)/2;
    console.log(zScale);
    console.log(imgHeight);
    
    img.animate({
      "left": "+="+movement,
      "top": "-="+movement
      
    },"slow");
   }
  setInterval(function(){
    startMoving();
  },1000)
});
```

If the image at the corner how can I restart image movement again from bottom left?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: may be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things using CSS transitions instead of JQuery `animate()`. This feature is easy to manage and with less code.

I've just created an initial CSS state and a final stage (`.end`), using jQuery to toggle the class to switch from initial/final position.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  setInterval(function(){
      $("#imageId").toggleClass("end");  
  },2000);
});
```

```css
img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  top: 95vh;
  left: 0;
  transition: linear 1s;
}
img.end{
  top: 0;
  left: 95vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imageId" class="start" width="48" height="48">
```